# Question edited and then closed because of duplicate. Why?

Tags: discussion

I ask a question.

[Is it possible to create nested Quicklists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70127/is-it-possible-to-create-nested-quicklists)

I asked "Is it possible to create nested quicklists in 11.10? Or will it be possible in 12.10?" because I want to know the **current** status of nestet quicklists. I also add tags for 11.10 and 12.04.

After just 5 minutes my post was edit to some generic question and now its closed becaus of a six month old "possible duplicate".

But I dont want to know what's in May and Ubuntu 11.04. I want to know what's NOW. So what's going on here? I know that there is another question. Thats why I add 11.10 and 12.04 tags.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not responsible for the edit but I did nail the coffin shut. With or without the edit, the question is completely duplicate (the older question talks about the future). The only difference is when they were asked.

We like to keep the number of open questions to a minimum especially when they're about the same thing. It would be unmanageable if every release, every question was re-asked.

My only suggestion is if you really want an answer, post a bounty (it can be a small one) or talk to the people in charge of steering Unity and ask them to post an answer.

Comment: well, I still dont know if nested quicklists are possible in Oneiric so the "duplicate" doesn't answer my question

Comment: The same logic applies. Starting a new question when an old needs updating will result in an unneccessary swarm of duplicates twice a year. Old posts need to be maintained.

Answer (score 2):

That was me sorry, I've untagged the version of the old one to make it clear it's not version specific. Sorry for the confusion!

Tip: You can post a bounty on a question and select the option to ask for updates for new versions, that's probably the easiest way to get something updated.

(Also the current answer still applies)